# How to make InputTable

Tags: inputfield

There is InputField in mma but how to make InputTable?
In MathCAD it`s possible to insert Excel spreadsheet with input and output variables.Input variables I use for filling of header row and column and output variable for output.
How to make the same functionality in mma?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Thanks for the accept, but there's no need for speed. It's better to give it a few hours or even days, so that more answers come in.

Comment: This MathCAD feature is very good but nothing like it exists built in to Mma. The closest is `TableView` which @SjoerdC.deVries has shown below. It is undocumented and falls *way short* of the MathCAD implementation. Fingers crossed for a full documented and better version for V9.

Answer (score 12):

```
nrows = 3; ncols = 4;
t = ConstantArray[0, {nrows, ncols}];
it = Table[With[{i = i, j = j}, InputField[Dynamic[t[[i, j]]]]], {i,nrows}, {j, ncols}];

Dynamic[TableView[it]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Another dynamic view to show it works:

```
Transpose[t] // TableView // Dynamic
```

(the `Transpose` here just used to show it actively uses the input).

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Please note that I used the undocumented `TableView` to make it more Excel-like, but I noticed that cell selection is a bit sluggish and/or unpredictable. You may want to change to `Grid` instead, which seems to work better.

Comment: @NasserM.Abbasi As you can see in the figures it is quite possible to enter data in all the rows (I work on the same platform as you), but there is a good reason for my advice to use `Grid`.

Comment: Dangerous to rely upon undocumented (even unreliable) `TableView`. It would be really convenient if `TableView` were implemented reliably and with documentation in a future Mathematica version, but that's something we cannot count on, of course. So `Grid` is probably better to use for now.

Comment: But inputed values dissapear after recalculation of notebook?!

Comment: @SergeyFomin Did you notice the line: `t = ConstantArray[0, {nrows, ncols}];` in the code? What do you think it does?

Comment: It initialize the array t of course.But I need to keep inputed values.I guess it`s obvious thing or no?

Comment: @SergeyFomin If you want to store data on disk, there are several methods for that. You may want to look up `Save`, `DumpSave`, `Put`, and `Write` in the documentation.

Comment: Thanks,but I don`t want to store data on disk in this particular case.May be replace Dynamic with DynamicModule?

Comment: @SergeyFomin If storage isn't your goal, then you just have to prevent that the initialization part is run again. Then the values are available as long as you keep the session running. DynamicModule and SaveDefinitions enable you to have variable contents survive the end of the session, but they write to hard disk as well, of course.

Comment: How to get local DynamicModule variable x.I can`t find any example in documentation?

Comment: @SergeyFomin You mean from outside the module? You can't. That's why it's called a local variable. You can return its value at the end of a call to the function of course. I'm afraid you really need to read more of the basics in the documentation.

Comment: Two years left and up to now TableView is undocumented feature.What is happening with super mma system?((

Comment: I suppose they had other priorities. Mathematica is a very broad system and its expansion is sometimes in areas that I'm not in the least interested in but that are a boon to others.